# SocketStream.js without client side how to?

Tags: node.js, rpc, socketstream

I am interested in develop a rt module for my website with socketstream + node.js. I am only interested in do the server side in socketstream, not the client side. How can I access the socketstream from a normal php/html app, wich js i have to include ?  I am mainly interested in rpc, pub/sub and authentication/session.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out to this framework:

> http://www.socketstream.org/

Comes with a lot of examples and it's easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend doing this, as it is unorthodox.

That said, I do recall that someone wanted to use an early version of SocketStream from within their application, which was built on the .net platform. It turned out that they got it to work by embedding the SocketStream app's web page inside of an iframe.